# Selecting javascript objects via their methods with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I select:

```
object.id2 == "name1";
```

with jQuery (instead of looping through all of the objects and finding the one who's `id2` matches `"name1"`), so I could write something like:

```
$("name1");
```

or maybe:

```
$(object + " name1");
```

or possibly:

```
$(object).attr('id2','name1');
```

Comment: [jQuery is meant for DOM selection](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif), if you need to select objects out of an array, i recommend using `Array.prototype.filter`.

Comment: If your objects are contained in an array, you can use jQuery to filter the array down to your target object using the filter method, the same way the Array.prototype.filter method mentioned above would do it, only, it would also work in IE<9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Lodash](http://lodash.com/):

```
var namedObjects = _.find(allObjects, { id2: 'name1' });
```

Comment: This answer definitely works, although I'm surprised plain jQuery can't do it.

Comment: @JVE999 it can, it just isn't built with this purpose in mind therefore it takes a little bit more code to do it.

Comment: @JVE999: Why? jQuery is about DOM manipulation, not objects.  Lodash is basically jQuery for objects.

Comment: It's very similar, search through objects and match a value, so I thought it would be able to. I though the DOM included the javascript as well. Lodash must be the answer then.

Comment: I noticed `_.find()` only returns the first match. Is there a way to return all of the matches using a similar method?

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObj = $('[id2="name1"]') 
//myObj will be an array if there is more than one element that matches
```

As seen here: [jQuery Selector API](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: If there's only one match, is myObj still an array? (So to access it, it would be `$('[id2="name1"]')[0]`?

Comment: well, technically it would never be an array, but it would always be an array-like object, even with only 1 object.

Comment: Very true @KevinB, nice!

Comment: Well, it did make a jQuery object, but it does not contain the object I'm looking for. It's a three.js mesh object with `mesh.id2="name1"`.

Comment: right, because the code in this answer is for selecting DOM elements.

Comment: Ah, I was trying to select a javascript object by a parameter (method?) with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best way to do it, but if you insist on doing it with jquery, this would be the way to do it:

```
var theArr = [{id2:"name0"},{id2:"name1"}];

var myObj = $(theArr).filter(function(){
    return this.id2 === "name1";
}).get(0);

console.log(myObj); // Object {id2: "name1"}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/kTxkr/

of course, if you don't have to support IE<9, you can cut jquery out without changing much:

```
var theArr = [{id2:"name0"},{id2:"name1"}];

var myObj = theArr.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.id2 === "name1";
})[0];

console.log(myObj); // Object {id2: "name1"}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/kTxkr/1

Comment: Awesome. I was not aware of `.filter`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but if you create an object like this:

```
var foo = {id2 : "name1"};
```

You can use a jQuery selector like this:

```
$(foo)
```

Comment: What about an object like this: `var foo = [{id2:"name0"},{id2:"name1"}];` IE, foo is an array instead.